# How to parse and print the characters {} with pgf and \thisrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a data table with "{}" I would like to keep these characters.

Results:
[image: lewis logic]

I would like to uningore this character from parsing to be printed on the image.

I know that I could to change:

```
nodes near coords*={\label},
```

to

```
nodes near coords*={\{\label\}},
```

But this do not allow me to print something like {{N}{F}}

My curent latex code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.12} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                        separate axis lines,
                        axis lines=left,
                        every outer x axis line/.append style={-stealth},
                        every outer y axis line/.append style={-stealth},
                        xmin=-1,xmax=7,
                        ymin=-1,ymax=7, 
                        xticklabels=\empty,
                        yticklabels=\empty,
                        zticklabels=\empty,
                        xlabel=$t$,
                        ylabel=$i$
                    ]
        \addplot[
                    nodes near coords*={\label},
                    nodes near coords align={right},
                    every node near coord/.style={font=\tiny,black},
                    mark=*,
                    only marks,
                    scatter,
                    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \label}
                ] table[x=t,y=i,meta=label]{
t f i label
0 6 0 {F}
6 0 0 {T}
3 3 0 {N}
3 3 3 {FT}
0 6 3 {NF}
6 0 3 {NT}
3 3 6 {NFT}
};
        % F - FT
        \draw[black,-] (0,0) to (3,3);
        % F - NF
        \draw[black,-] (0,0) to (0,3);
        % NF - NFT
        \draw[black,-] (0,3) to (3,6);
        % NFT - FT
        \draw[black,-] (3,6) to (3,3);
        % NFT - NT
        \draw[black,-] (3,6) to (6,3);
        % NT - T
        \draw[black,-] (6,3) to (6,0);
        % T - FT
        \draw[black,-] (6,0) to (3,3);
        % N - NF
        \draw[black,-] (3,0) to (0,3);
        % N - NT
        \draw[black,-] (3,0) to (6,3);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *printed* braces, you have to tell LaTeX so: change your data into

```
t f i label
0 6 0 \{F\}
6 0 0 \{T\}
3 3 0 \{N\}
3 3 3 \{FT\}
0 6 3 \{NF\}
6 0 3 \{NT\}
3 3 6 \{NFT\}
```

and you get

[image]

Here's the full code. I just changed `{` and `}` into `\{` and `\}` in the relevant places and added `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.12} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                        separate axis lines,
                        axis lines=left,
                        every outer x axis line/.append style={-stealth},
                        every outer y axis line/.append style={-stealth},
                        xmin=-1,xmax=7,
                        ymin=-1,ymax=7, 
                        xticklabels=\empty,
                        yticklabels=\empty,
                        zticklabels=\empty,
                        xlabel=$t$,
                        ylabel=$i$
                    ]
        \addplot[
                    nodes near coords*={\label},
                    nodes near coords align={right},
                    every node near coord/.style={font=\tiny,black},
                    mark=*,
                    only marks,
                    scatter,
                    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \label}
                ] table[x=t,y=i,meta=label]{
t f i label
0 6 0 \{F\}
6 0 0 \{T\}
3 3 0 \{N\}
3 3 3 \{FT\}
0 6 3 \{NF\}
6 0 3 \{NT\}
3 3 6 \{NFT\}
};
        % F - FT
        \draw[black,-] (0,0) to (3,3);
        % F - NF
        \draw[black,-] (0,0) to (0,3);
        % NF - NFT
        \draw[black,-] (0,3) to (3,6);
        % NFT - FT
        \draw[black,-] (3,6) to (3,3);
        % NFT - NT
        \draw[black,-] (3,6) to (6,3);
        % NT - T
        \draw[black,-] (6,3) to (6,0);
        % T - FT
        \draw[black,-] (6,0) to (3,3);
        % N - NF
        \draw[black,-] (3,0) to (0,3);
        % N - NT
        \draw[black,-] (3,0) to (6,3);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks egreg. I tried your solution (in sharelatex) with both pdflatex and xelatex but an error is raised: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

Comment: @bioinfornatics Tell them to upgrade their TeX distribution. `;-)`

Comment: hehe, I will do :-)

Comment: could you put the full tex file to generate your image please? I tried  to do it on my computer. but I have always a stack size problem even if I increase the max stack size and others.

Comment: @bioinfornatics I just changed `{` and `}` into `\{` and `\}`. I added the full code. It could be a version problem, if you're unable to compile it.